# how to uninstall dxwebsetup on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: directx

I would like to remove/uninstall directX End-User that I downloaded and installed it from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=35

I see that it is not needed on my Server anymore but I can not find it to uninstall on "Programs and Features".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to remove DirectX from your system is to use a windows restore point in System restore or wipe and remove the OS.

See last comment here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/gametechnologiesdirectx101/thread/e1bcfc66-b9e2-4541-a310-cdf3f998028f/

Comment: it is the directX SDK redistributes.